# Invalid Child Element

Tags: xml, schema, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-schemas

I am trying to do some experiment on envelope in BizTalk 2010 when one message will compose of multiple items. I have the schema for the envelope as follow:

Envelope:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://TestFromMSDN" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://TestFromMSDN" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo is_envelope="yes" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Envelope">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo body_xpath="/*[local-name()='Envelope' and namespace-uri()='http://TestFromMSDN']" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The schema for individual item is as follow. Each envelope could contain multiple items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://TestFromMSDN" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://TestFromMSDN" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Error">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="Priority" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="ErrorDateTime" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When I tried to create my xml data, BizTalk does not like my xml and had a squiggly line on my second item, saying invalid child element.

[image]

Can someone point out what is wrong in my data?

```
<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://TestFromMSDN">
  <ns0:Error>
    <ns0:ID>102</ns0:ID>
    <ns0:Type>0</ns0:Type>
    <ns0:Priority>High</ns0:Priority>
    <ns0:Description>Sproket query fails</ns0:Description>
    <ns0:ErrorDateTime>1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00</ns0:ErrorDateTime>
  </ns0:Error>
  <ns0:Error>
    <ID>16502</ID>
    <Type>2</Type>
    <Priority>Low</Priority>
    <Description>Time threshold exceeded</Description>
    <ErrorDateTime>1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00</ErrorDateTime>
  </ns0:Error>
</ns0:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the number of items in the sequence is 1. You should specify `maxOccurs` to be unbounded or the exact number of items you expect on your `Envelope` element (I have removed annotation for clarity):

```
<xs:element name="Envelope">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:any />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Another suggestion: if you are expecting *only* `Error` elements inside `Envelope`, a better practice is to specify `<xs:Error/>`instead of `<xs:any/>`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the maxOccurs. No wonder it gave out weird warnings. As for <xs:any/>, my goal is to hopefully catch anything and not just <xs:Error/>. I hope I can throw anything in there in the future and not just error message. Hopefully, this is not against good practice.